# Object occlusion issues with camera plugin for ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I created two simple SDF models to represent a wall section and a door prop (that is, just a board with the picture of a door on it). When I place a "door" in front of a wall and get a camera (via the ROS camera plugin) to record the scene,

[image: image description]

The door appears behind the wall in the camera image, even though it is clearly in front of it in the environment view.

[image: image description]

However if I use the "Brick Box 3x1x3" from the model library instead of my own wall model, images are generated correctly:

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

What could be the problem here?

The wall SDF model and texture script are:

`yumebros_room_wall_240cm2.sdf`

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name='yumebros_room_wall_240cm2'>
    <static>true</static>
    <link name='link'>
      <pose>0 0 1.2 0 0 0</pose>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.2 2.4 2.4</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.2 2.4 2.4</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>model://yumebros_room_wall_240cm2/materials/scripts</uri>
            <uri>model://yumebros_room_wall_240cm2/materials/textures</uri>
            <name>Yumebros/RoomWallSurface</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

`white_paint.material`

```
material Yumebros/RoomWallSurface
{
  technique
  {
    pass
    {
      texture_unit
      {
        texture white_paint.png
        scale 0.125 0.125
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for the door:

`yumebros_door_blue.sdf`

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name='yumebros_door_blue'>
    <pose>0 0 1.05 0 0 0</pose>
    <static>1</static>
    <link name='link'>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.05 0.92 2.1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.05 0.92 2.1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>model://yumebros_door_blue/materials/scripts</uri>
            <uri>model://yumebros_door_blue/materials/textures</uri>
            <name>Yumebros/DoorBlue</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <self_collide>1</self_collide>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

`door_blue.material`

```
material Yumebros/DoorBlue
{
  technique
  {
    pass
    {
      texture_unit
      {
        texture door_blue.png
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/11286/object-occlusion-issues-with-camera-plugin-for-ros/) by [xperroni](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1217/xperroni/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kke](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2730/kke/) on 2016-07-25**:
Im having the same problem with gazebo 5.3 on ubuntu. The background wall appears in front of the object when looking through a gazebo camera object. In my case it is with both textured and untextured walls. The same world setting had no problem with gazebo 5.1.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-07-26**:
Can you try gazebo7?

**Comment by [kke](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2730/kke/) on 2016-07-27**:
im working with ros jade so the recommended version is 5.x. I havent tried updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Turns out this is a [known issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1837/vmware-rendering-z-ordering-appears-random) in Gazebo. Apparently it is related to specific graphic card driver issues. Currently the only possible solution is to recompile Gazebo with a changed parameter; see Xander Dunn's answer for details.

---

Originally posted by [xperroni](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1217/xperroni/) with karma: 11 on 2016-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0